# How to check if database entry is older than 1 day in javascript

Tags: javascript, database, node.js

I am making a node.js application that uses this database manager: https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb.

I have a database containing a message like this:

```
{"mes":"hi","username":"hello","number":1,"date":"Fri Oct 24 2014 10:42:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)","_id":"Zzi6OQVnoSXKYlHR"}
```

I want it to delete all messages older than 1 day. So I made something else like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
        db.find({}).sort({ number: -1 }).exec(function (err, docs) {
            var arrayLength = docs.length;
            tDate = new Date();
            tDate = tDate.toString();
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

            }
        });
},5000);
```

Which every 5 seconds goes through every entry in the database. So how would I, using the database entries, could check if the oldest one is older than 1 day?

Comment: By database you mean... object?

Comment: "Fri Oct 24 2014 10:42:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" is not a good way to store a date. It would be more convenient to use either an ISO 8601 string or a time value (e.g. milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

Comment: No, I mean database. You see, I use this: https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb to keep hold of all the messages. So I popped open the database file, and that was what I found. Also, variable docs contains a array of all those objects, and I contains the current one.

Comment: So u want to get messages with age less than 24 hrs??

Comment: And then delete them, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some small issues with your code.

Using setInterval for something like this is a poor choice. What happens if the previous interval is still running when the last has not finished? It might be fine here, but for more complex logic errors could occur.

You'd be better storing dates without a specific format. use new Date().toJSON() or Date.now() to get a better format without having to worry about timezones.

Don't use a for loop unless the dataset (docs) will be very small, otherwise each delete write will build up into a huge number of concurrent writes (unless you batch them)

```
var moment = require('moment');
var async = require('async');

function deleteDoc(doc, callback) { // Run delete then fire callback }

function deleteOld () {
  // Get start of day in milliseconds
  var startOfToday = moment.utc(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')).valueOf();

  db.find({$lt: {date: startOfTheDay}}).sort({ number: -1 }).exec(function (err, docs) {
    async.eachSeries(docs, deleteDoc, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err)

      setTimeout(deleteOld, 5000);
    });
  })
}

deleteOld()
```

Assuming you use the Date.now() method for "date" the above will only return day old entries and delete them.

Comment: Thank You! It worked, though I had to make some modifications. This is it now:
function deleteDoc(doc, callback) {
    db.remove(doc, function (err, numRemoved) {});
    callback();
}

function deleteOld () {
  // Get start of day in milliseconds
  var startOfToday = moment.utc(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')).valueOf();
  db.find({ date: { $gt: startOfToday }}, function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    async.eachSeries(docs, deleteDoc, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      setTimeout(deleteOld, 5000);
    });
  })
}